# Cannot boot with EFI

Tags: 16.04, bootloader, grub-efi

I was [having problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764699/) with repairing my boot loader (grub). My GParted config looked like:
[image]

I installed another Ubuntu to the free space which restored my grub. But when booting into my old partition, I get into emergency mode, "Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0".  So still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by going to advanced option and booting with 3.X kernel (upstart).

It has been practically impossible to decrypt my home directory from another partition (that's what I tried first) and fixing the boot to the old partition is a clever way around that.

Lesson learned: don't use os-uninstaller to clean up the various Windows partitions before you know what you are doing.