# Ubuntu boot partition corrupted after using DBAN on an external disk

Tags: boot, ssd

**Solution: So using DBAN to wipe an external disk corrupted/wiped my EFI partition on my main SSD drive. The solution for this problem was that I followed the steps from [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432) as suggested by Karsus (thank you!) noting that sda1 was formatted fat32 and flagged boot but did not show as efi (as demonstrated in https://askubuntu.com/a/764702/13398).**

Original post:

So I’m going to give you quick story and I’ll get into details. I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop and have been using it for quite some time. Yesterday I needed to wipe a drive so I booted my laptop via a USB drive that had the Ultimate Boot Cd and ran Darik’s Boot and Nuke (DBAN) of the external drive. When I rebooted the laptop failed to boot. I get an error: “PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable”

`So details: 
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Laptop: Toshiba Satellite P50-B
Hd: PNY Optima Series 240GB SSD (SSD7SC240GOPT-RB)
UBCD: 1.9.5.7 – DBAN ?`

I booted an ubuntu usb boot image and looked at the drive with gparted. The three partitions are still there: boot sector, data, and linux swap. Furthermore all my data is still there as well (and now backed up). So I’m guessing somehow the boot sector got corrupted? Is there a simple way to fix this or is it just time to install 16.04 and call it a day?

Ok, Thank you Karsus, you reminded me of a comment I forgot to make. In order to run the usb boots I had to switch from UEFI boot to CSM boot. I also switched the boot order but have reverted that. I only get the PXE-E61 error in CSM mode. In UEFI mode I simply get "Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key". ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what's listed [there](https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?2655-PXE-E61-Media-Test-Failure-check-cable) the problem may be in the boot sequence. Try entering the BIOS and checking that everything is correct.

edit:

The new error also suggests you are trying to boot from an incorrect boot device. But since you have reverted the boot order changes it could well be a corrupted boot partition. In that case you probably need to repair grub from a live USB. Check that [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/498541) and/or [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/145253/498541) for details on how to do it. Be sure that you mount the proper devices for your system configuration.

Comment: Please see the update!

Comment: Updated answer. I think repairing grub is the next step to salvage the situation.