# Cannot boot my Windows after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader

I can't boot my Windows. Windows boot option is not listed in GRUB boot list.

Boot-repair gave me [this info summary](https://paste2.org/BxBf0nfK).

Comment: Often, with Boot Repair, users have more success by obtaining the report and then asking here than actually applying the fix. I suggest [edit]ing the question to include that.

Comment: check this after edit

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

The "good stuff" in boot repair report is often found at the bottom. Such is the case in your situation:

```
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda7/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

See this Q&A: [Ubuntu 16.04 + Windows 10 Hibernated = no OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838818/ubuntu-16-04-windows-10-hibernated-no-os)