# Cannot start something different than Windows 10 after update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I had dual boot. Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Yesterday after updating Windows grub stopped to work and I was unable to do anything with the PC. It is desktop PC. When I tried to boot with live USB and I choose:
"Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" I got the following error:

```
[  0.020613] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.XHX_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure,
 AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/dswload-210)
[  0.20619] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (2016093
0/psobject-227)
[  0.020644] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rvp10) while loading table
(20160930/tbxfload-228)
```

and PC froze and the black startup screen gets filled with blurred text. I tried to fix grub but there was no partition that which can be recognized as some Linux partition. After that I tried to use Windows live USB and to clean MBR. Windows managad to update and I have Windows now but when I try to boot from Ubuntu Live USB I got the same error. How to fix Ubuntu installation? I tried with Ubuntu DVD also and I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Windows, Windows assumes it is the only operating system (OS) on the machine, or at least it does not account for Linux. So it replaces GRUB with its own boot loader. What you have to do is replace the Windows boot loader with GRUB. I've seen various instructions for replacing GRUB by mucking around with GRUB commands or some such, but to me the easiest way is to simply `chroot` into your install and run `update-grub`. `chroot` is great because it allows you to work on your actual install, instead of trying to redirect things here and there. It is really clean.

Here's how:

1. Boot from the live CD or live USB, in "Try Ubuntu" mode.
2. Determine the partition number of your main partition. GParted (which should already be installed, by default, on the live session) can help you here. I'm going to assume in this answer that it's `/dev/sda2`, but **make sure you use the correct partition number for your system!**
3. Mount your partition:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt   #Replace sda2 with your partition number
   ```
4. Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

   ```
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
   ```
5. If Ubuntu is installed in EFI mode ([see this answer if you're unsure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764699/does-this-answer-work-for-uefi-computers/764702#764702)), use GParted to find your EFI partition. It will have a label of EFI. Mount this partition, replacing sdXY with the actual partition number for your system:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot/efi
   ```
6. `chroot` into your Ubuntu install:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
7. At this point, you're in your install, not the live session, and running as root. Update grub:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```

   If you get errors or if going up to step 7 didn't fix your problem, go to step 8. (Otherwise, it is optional.)
8. Depending on your situation, you might have to reinstall grub:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   update-grub # In order to find and add windows to grub menu.
   ```
9. If everything worked without errors, then you're all set:

   ```
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```
10. At this point, you should be able to boot normally.
    If you cannot boot normally, and didn't do step 8 because there were no error messages, try again with step 8.

Sometimes giving GRUB2 the correct configuration for your partitions is not enough, and you must actually install it (or reinstall it) to the Master Boot Record, which step 8 does. Experience helping users in chat has shown that step 8 is sometimes necessary even when no error messages are shown.

Comment: The problem is in that this errors happens even when I try to boot from live USB and live CD.

Comment: Try making a fresh copy of Ubuntu in the USB after a proper format. I think that must solve the issue. You don't need to install the Ubuntu again, the OS is still there but the grub menu is itself revoked by Windows after the update. Hence, you follow the above steps to get it back.

Comment: This is really strange problem because I made live USB in another PC, test it and it works properly but when I boot from it and choose "try ubuntu" and "install ubuntu" on this PC there is the same error. I will try again this evening.

Comment: Sure. Try with a fresh boot install and let me know.

Comment: Error is the same - with fresh boot. :(

Comment: Try adding "libata.noacpi=1" (without the quotes) in the grub.cfg file. You can access it using the instructions given here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters#GRUB. Post me about the updates. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63532/discussion-between-brijesh-jain-and-george).